# How to add shortcode in wordpress using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to put a shortcode in a WordPress website using JavaScript.

Website structure is

```
<div class="shop-container">
    <div class="wrap">[shortcode here]</div>
    <div class="wc-pr"> </div>
</div>
```

Firstly, i put div element to above wc-pr using below code.

```
<script>
    const parent5 = document.querySelector('.shop-container');
    const billingField1 = document.querySelector('.wc-pr');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrap');

    parent5.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
</script>
```

Then i tried below code.

```
newDiv.innerHTML = `<?php do_shortcode("[shortcode here]");?>`;
newDiv.innerText = `<?php do_shortcode("[shortcode here]");?>`;
```

But not working. innertext is diplayed as raw, Hhtml is not showing.

Please let me know how do i solve this

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating/generating an HTML, so you must echo it to the script. So just adding echo to the PHP

`newDiv.innerHTML = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode here]");?>';`

instead of

`newDiv.innerHTML = '<?php do_shortcode("[shortcode here]");?>';`

should do it.